# disable the range of cells on another sheet ( say Sheet2) based on the value in the current sheet(say Sheet1)

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to disable the range of cells on another sheet ( say Sheet4) based on the value in the current sheet(say Sheet1)

I have tried to disable the values in the sheet4("M4,M6,M8,M10,M12") based on the values in sheet1("C5") by using worksheet change function.

With Sheet1 I have used the below code and getting the error message

> Subscript Out of Range

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        Dim myRng As Range    
        Dim Cancel As Boolean

        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C5")) Is Nothing Then
            Set myRng = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("M4,M6,M8,M10,M12")
            Me.Unprotect Password:=SHEET_PASSWORD

            If Me.Range("C5").Value = "Yes" Then
                myRng.Locked = False
            Else
                myRng.Locked = True
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4").Range("M4,M6,M8,M10,M12") = ""
            End If
            Me.Protect Password:=SHEET_PASSWORD
        End If

End Sub
```

If I choose "Yes" in the cell value C5 in Sheet1, the cell values (M4,M6,M8,M10,M12) in sheet4 should be enabled. If i choose "No" in the cell value C5 in Sheet1, the cell values (M4,M6,M8,M10,M12) in sheet4 should be disabled.

Comment: Please be consistent in what you talk about (you talk about `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` in your text but you have `Sheet4` in your code (reading [mcve] might help). Also `ChangeEventFlag` is not defined and this code cannot run because an `End If` is missing. Please [edit] and improve your question. Also **tell in which line** you get errors and which. And actually you didn't ask a question.

Comment: What is ChangeEventFlag? You did not close the first If with an End If

Comment: @Pᴇʜ I think you found the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**I think This is what you are looking For.**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If ChangeEventFlag = 0 Then
        Dim myRng As Range
        Dim Cancel As Boolean

        If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C5")) Is Nothing Then
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet4")

            .Unprotect Password:="password"
            .Cells.Locked = False

            Set myRng = .Range("M4,M6,M8,M10,M12")

            If Me.Range("C5").Value = "Yes" Then
                myRng.Locked = False
            Else
                myRng.Locked = True
                myRng.Value  = ""
            End If
                .Protect Password:="password"
            End With

        End If
    End If

End Sub
```

**Note:**

- Not sure about the use of `ChangeEventFlag`
- Change the Password, I used `password` for testing

**Use:**

Whichever sheet you will paste this code on will Lock `Range("M4,M6,M8,M10,M12")` of `Sheet4` if it's `C5` is **No(Anything Other Than Yes Actually)** and will unlock it if `C5` is **Yes**

Comment: Just a note: The idea of using `Password:=SHEET_PASSWORD` was to put the password into a private constant `Private Const SHEET_PASSWORD As String = "password"` so if you need to change the password later you only need to change it in one position and you don't forget one instance to replace.